# Docker and MongoDB replica set with user authentication

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I want to run MongoDB replica set using docker compose file. After some searches I found this article ([MongoDB And Docker](https://flowygo.com/en/blog/mongodb-and-docker-how-to-create-and-configure-a-replica-set/)), which works with no problem.

But I want to add user authentication to my database, which requires a key file, so I modified the docker-compose file and added a new volume for key file and --keyFile flag to entrypoint, but when I try to run it with "docker-compose up".

It returns this error:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-08T23:20:48.613+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20575,
"ctx":"main","msg":"Error creating service context",
"attr":{"error":"Location5579201: Unable to acquire security key[s]"}}
```

Here is my new docker-compose file

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  mongodb1:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb1
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - mongodata1:/data/db
      - /mnt/c/Projects/docker/replicaset/mongo-setup/key:/key.key
    expose:
      - "27017"
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB", "1", "--keyFile", "./key.key" ]

  mongodb2:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb2
    volumes:
      - mongodata2:/data/db
      - /mnt/c/Projects/docker/replicaset/mongo-setup/key:/key.key
    expose:
      - "27017"
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB", "1", "--keyFile", "./key.key" ]

  mongosetup:
    image: "mongo-setup"
    build: "./mongo-setup"
    container_name: "mongosetup"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb1
    volumes:
      - mongostatus:/data/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does the running docker container have visibility to the keyfile?  Also, I believe the image `mongo` is a linux variant.  If so the permissions on the keyfile have to be 400.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/

Comment: @barrypicker thanks for response, first I don't exactly understand what you mean by " container have visibility to the key file"?? second I had tried to change the key file permission before but when I print the result of "ls -l key.key" in container, it says `-r-xr-xr-x 1 1000 1000 1024 Dec  7 16:59 key.key` for changing file permission, I've change entrypoint to ` entrypoint: > bash -c "cat ./key.key && chmod 400 ./key.key && /usr/bin/mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 1"`

Comment: for containerized solutions I generally want to acquire a bash command line interpreter of the container and look around to see if the environment is as expected - files exist, permissions set, processes started, etc.  Assuming you are using docker (since you are using dockercompose) you can view the running docker containers by issuing the command `docker ps -a`.  Here you can identify your running docker containers - can be multiple containers running - each is a VM.  In this output try to identify the container id.

Comment: Once you have the container ID you can connect and get a bash command line...  Use the command `docker exec -i -t <CONTAINER ID> /bin/bash` to get a command line interpreter.  The container must be running for this command to work.  If the container is not running you must get it be running first.  Once inside the container with a bash command line, verify the key file has the correct permissions.  While here you can try to start MongoDB if not already started, and/or view the log files at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` (for startup problems)

Comment: @barrypicker I've done that before, and the permissions that I mentioned before is the permissions shown in docker container. if it can do any help you can find my codes here: [https://github.com/saeedNW/docker/tree/master/replicaset](https://github.com/saeedNW/docker/tree/master/replicaset)